# T-SQL: Determine upline and downline from hierarchy without the Parent ID

Tags: t-sql, hierarchy

I have this self-referencing table where-in I should get the upline and downline and hierarchy levels without the Parent ID provided.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your extremely vague question requires much more detail be given if you want any sort of helpful answers. At the bare minimum you should provide the table schema and some sample data, as well as what your expected results should be based on that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using recursive CTE?
for example:
assume you have table tbl(EmpId, Name, MngrId) which has self-referencing relationship

```
create table tbl
(
EmpId  int not null, 
Name nvarchar(100), 
MngrId int null) 

insert into tbl(EmpId, Name, MngrId)
values  (1,'Adel',Null),
        (2,'Ali',1),
        (3,'Shaban',1),
        (4,'Mark',3),
        (5,'John',3),
        (6,'Tony',Null),
        (7,'Peter',6)
```

You can create some view like that:

```
create view Employees
Begin

with cte 
as
(
Select EmpId,Name, Null as MngrId, cast(null as nvarchar(100)) as MngrName, 1 as EmpLevel
from tbl
where MngrId is Null
Union All
Select t.EmpId, t.Name, c.EmpId as MngrId, c.Name as MngrName, c.EmpLevel + 1 as EmpLevel
from tbl t
inner join cte c
on t.MngrId =  c.EmpId
)
Select *
from cte
order by EmpLevel, EmpId

End
```

You can now use `EmpLevel` to jump between different levels and `MngrName` to get information about parent node